# Proxy DLL for ieframe.dll

Tags: windows-xp, dll, dep

I have created a template proxy dll for ieframe.dll using wrappit (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16541/Create-your-Proxy-DLLs-automatically)

Currently, I am trying to hook it to test if it works before modifying any function, however, when I tried it, Windows starts throwing out DEP errors and explorer.exe keeps crashing, as such, I tried disabling DEP for Windows Explorer, but explorer still keep crashing. Restarting the machine doesn't work either.

I am wondering if there is ieframe.dll is anything different about ieframe.dll in particular as compared to other dlls. Previously, I have created a proxy dll for advapi32.dll using the same method and there wasn't any issue with the hooking nor the DEP. Any ideas?

EDIT: I am using Windows XP SP3